# Is there a CSS parser for C#?

Tags: c#, css, parsing

My program need to parse css files into an in-memory object format. Any advice on how this should be done ?

Comment: I don't get why this question was closed. It has got a lot of votes from people apparently wondering the same thing. Just because different people might have different opinions about the best solution, what a great place to list those opinions for others with the same question.

Comment: @JonathanWood - I entirely agree, but the policy is that tool recommendations are off topic, and it is asking for a tool recommendation.  So closing it is appropriate, even if frustrating.

Comment: I've rewroten the question so it can be reopened

Comment: @Softlion, by doing so you seem to have invalidated all six of the existing answers, none of which talk about Linq. IMO it would be preferable to rollback, post a new question, and then link to that new question in a comment on this one.

Comment: You were right, I removed "Linq" as it was not present in the initial question.

Comment: When I searched for a css parser in C#, I stumbled upon this question so it is obviously valuable.

Answer (score 28):

ExCSS (supports CSS2.1 and CSS3) on GitHub: https://github.com/TylerBrinks/ExCSS.

Which is a newer version of the code project article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx

Comment: wish it would parse out the media query into an object model. it's not particularly hard to do so but all it gives you is a string

Comment: it works, but found a number of things it can't parse: `calc(50vw - 23em)` becomes `calc(50vw = 23em)` / `3rem` becomes `3` / `z-index: 2147483647` becomes `z-index: 2.147484E+09` / `*display: none` becomes `display: none`

Comment: It also does not handle `@-ms-viewport` returning `{System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[ExCSS.RuleSet]}` in output.

Answer (score 8):

And a slightly slower search turns up the blog post "[CSS parser class in .NET](http://blog.dynamicprogrammer.com/2008/01/20/CSSParserClassInNET.aspx)" which embeds [this gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/561823) (in case the blog ever dies).

Comment: ...ah-and it died

Answer (score 6):

There is a CSS grammar file for GoldParser:

http://goldparser.org/grammars/files/css.zip

GoldParser is easy to include in a C# project, and generates an real LALR parser - not some regex hack.

Comment: LALR parser - not some regex 

Info on their site
"GOLD grammars are based on Backus-Naur form and regular expressions"

Comment: Good point, regexs are cool.  Rolling a parser by hand isn't

Comment: This is a very simplified version of the CSS grammar. Instead I ported the CSS reference grammer (from the CSS 2.1 spec) to work with the GOLD parser ... and I've written a C# assembly to implement the rest of it (use the parser output to compute the style for an element in a DOM, using rule specificity, inheritance, default values, etc.).

Comment: Goldparser is nice but it is extremely slow. Even in speed optimized C++ code it takes 10 seconds to parse a 15000 lines of code. If you compare this with the speed of the PHP parser this is extremely slow.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [one featured in JsonFx](http://code.google.com/p/jsonfx/source/browse#svn/trunk/JsonFx/JsonFx.BuildTools/CssCompactor)? It's written in C#, parses CSS3 syntax and is distributed under a MIT style license.

Comment: Looks like the best of a bad bunch (recursion using `goto` statements - ouch)

Comment: @B: `goto` is a great way to *avoid* recursion, because it avoids re-entering a function.  It's a great alternative to risking a stack overflow when you have an potentially high number of iterations.

Comment: ...because you risk a stack overflow when you have a potentially high number of iterations. :D

Comment: Tail recursion to the rescue....

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one, using the grammar specified in the CSS 2.1 spec. I have also released it now: for details, see http://www.modeltext.com/css/

Comment: Cool. Is it available for the rest of us to try/buy?

Comment: Send email: my gmail id is "cwellsx".

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://itecharch.blogspot.com/2008/09/css-parser.html) you can find another one especially for C# with sample source.

Comment: this uses regular expressions which just isn't going to cut it for complex css