# How to load cascading style sheet into C# object?

Tags: c#, css, object

I am developing a web application, where i want to give freedom of changing style elements of css linked to a page via an admin screen. So I am wondering is there any way I can load CSS file into a C# object or into XML passable formate and update it from the admin screen inputs?
Thank you,
Krishnaraj

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a CSS parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512720/is-there-a-css-parser-for-c

Comment: @C.Ross I am on MVC
@jorn-schou-rode All the posts given in the above link talk about parsing the CSS. But I am for looking something like HTML Agility Pack(HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT), on which I can apply xpath to manipulate its content.

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting article about [parsing CSS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx) in CodeProject. I need to check how I can customize it to suite my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create several themes and change them in the admin section. Also you can create different skins for your controls.

Links: [ASP.NET Themes and Skins Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx), 
[How to: Apply ASP.NET Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yy5hxdk(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ASP.NET MVC**, you can create new `ActionResult` type called CssResult that dynamically generates a CSS.  An example of how to write a custom `ActionResult` can be found [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: I went though the link, but I am not sure whether I will be able to load css file into an c# object and fire XPATH over it. 

I must give freedom to user to choose style elements such as height, color, font, font style etc. I will provide a default style elements which user can customize himself. So I will be having a default css file, elements of which I want to populate over the web form and user can change the element values. When he clicks on Finish/Save, I want to save these new values in to the same CSS file. Any idea how can I achieve this??