# Regular Expression for valid css and/or jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, css, regex, jquery-selectors

I need something like this :

```
Regex validSelector = new Regex("^[.#a-zA-Z0-9_:[] ]+[,><a-zA-Z0-9_~=\"\":[] ]*$");
```

Has anybody written a regular expression for validating jQuery or CSS selectors?
(CSS3/jQuery1.4)

Or, does anybody know where I can find a regex or regex generator to validate a jQuery selector?(or atleast CSS selectors?)

I've tried going through the code of [sizzle.js](http://sizzlejs.com/) bu John Resig and the w3c docs for css (http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) but ended up havin a headache  :(

Thought i'd rather ask if any of you has already written or used some snippet for this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Technically, I don't think there are any invalid selectors, just some that don't select anything. At any rate, tasks such as brace matching and handling different contexts (normal, inside square brackets, inside quotes) are very regex-unfriendly, and typically done with a parser of some sort.

Comment: @Jonathan: From his code snippet, I'm guessing he wants to do this in C#.

Comment: @T.J. the snippet looks somewhat generic, but yeah, you're probably right

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, that *plus* the tag. ;-)

Comment: @Tgr - But there are invalid classnames (e.g. starts with numeric) so, by extension, a selector that matches an invalid classname could be considered invalid? Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names/449005#449005

Comment: You can build the regular expression right from the [grammar of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar).

Comment: @TJ, Jonathan: I included the c# tag, assuming somebody, somewhere might already have this in their helper library or somethin..  Or atleast know about something relevant.

Comment: @Jonathan Day: sorry I wasn't clear, I was talking about jQuery selctors, not CSS. `.123` is a jQuery selector that selects the (invalid) class `123` (try it in your browser of choice, it actually works). Whether that makes the jQuery selector itself invalid is up to debate. Also, jQuery's selector language is very open, you can easily add your own operators, or even change what `.` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Specification of CSS 3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) has a section about the [grammar of selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar) that you can use to build the regular expression. Just start with *selector* and replace each variable with its production until there are no variables left.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions don't make great *parsers*. (They may make great *parts* of a parser.) If you really need to do it, you'll probably need to actually use a parser. The [answers to this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512720/is-there-a-css-parser-for-c) on StackOverflow may help there.

Comment: This other question didn't show up in my relevant searches, thanks!