# Download complete web page

Tags: .net, html-parsing

Are there any existing frameworks that can download a complete web page (not a web site): A HTML page, it's style sheets, (javascripts) and images?

I would like to avoid parsing the HTML and stylesheets myself if possible.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/14403.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - this will definitely do the HTML part.

You will be able to easily query it for linked images, stylesheets and javascript files, but it can't handle those.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512720/is-there-a-css-parser-for-c) SO question for CSS parsing.

Apart from using [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), I can't think of any Javascript parser for .NET.

Comment: I ended up using AgilityPack and a simple regex to extract images from CSS.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) CLI tool. It has a `-p` option for a complete web-page:

```
wget -p www.yousite/page.html
```