# Parse css for background images

Tags: c#, css

I'm tasked with a web scraping project.  We are pulling a bunch of our static content into a CMS.

HtmlAgilityPack lets me grab dependent resources by looking for anything with a src or http=, but what about css files and their background images?  Is there a good utility for parsing css files to get this?

My current solution is a bit of the [cthulu](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) way of doing this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"url\(.*\)");
     foreach (var item in r.Matches(cssText))     
     {
    ///scrub url and     
    ///mark img for download
     }
```

Comment: Not sure this is a good answer, so I'm tentatively putting it in a comment. If I was tasked with this, I'd be tempted to let the browser do the work. Rig up a bookmarklet that fires off some jQuery, traverses the page and spews image URLs into the console. Then copy/paste the console output from wandering around the site into a text file and process that further in a text editor.

Comment: I almost went down this path, but I wasn't sure how to start reinventing what firebug does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parser for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512720/is-there-a-css-parser-for-c)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the resources in that question aren't actually much help for getting the values of properties.  At least I couldn't get JsonFx's tools to do me any good.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's not cthulu at all. Your solution sounds good enough for me.. and probably even a good example to use regexp.

Comment: Downvote reason: the concepts "regex" and "html parsing" do not belong together. A simple google search of this site will show you the shear number of issues surrounding this.  For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I ask you: Do you know the difference between CSS and HTML? Did you read cthulu?

Comment: (edited so I could remove the downvote).  In this extremely limited case, it *might* be okay to do this.