# How can I list available Css Classes from my App_Themes folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, app-themes

How to get a list of Css classes from a chosen Theme in App_Themes folder and display them in a DropDownList control?

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe able to parse the CSS code from each of the css files within the theme's folder using this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx and then show the classes in a list or dropdown.

Also take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512720/is-there-a-css-parser-for-c)